# Is blocking of javascripts and Ajax calls widespread and common

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a simple web page that utilizes frames to display any of five (5) possible screens that the user accesses by clicking on a tab at the top of the page.  In an effort to improve my site and increase views, I have written a number of javascripts and Ajax calls which log which tab is being viewed and for how long to a SQL database.  I know it works because I've tested it myself.  However, I don't seem to be getting much data into my SQL database from other site visitors.  I know that users can block javascripts but is that so commonplace that I won't be able to get any useful data.  If so, is there an alternative that I should consider.

Comment: Maybe there are just not many people visiting your site?

Comment: What do you mean by "useful data"?

Comment: `widespread`,  I would say no,.  But there are people who might.  One idea is just have a `<noscript>` tag with a redirect, and have your backend log this page.

Comment: You could also look at your web server logs to see how many visitors - don't rely on Google Analytics as this requires JavaScript to be enabled in the browser. If you have cPanel then you can use awstats for this info.

Comment: The one and only thing that I am getting from my user log that is of any use is the number of visitors.  That only requires a script that executes on loading of the page.  I am averaging about 50 visitors per day (small I am sure by the standards of many) but, if my user log can be believed, they are only looking at the home screen with the occasional page refresh.  They aren't opening any of the other tabs.  I find that difficult to believe.

Comment: Guest271314 - Useful information like are they visiting my services tab? how much time are they spending there? What services do they show the most interest in?

Comment: I may have just answered my own question.  Please check my thinking and respond.  If my user log is registering actions from the onload javascript, web site users are not blocking my javascripts and Ajax calls.  They cannot selectively block my javascripts and Ajax calls, can they?